# Java function call with changing parameter amount

Tags: java, function, methods, dynamic, runtime

I have a question.
While my program is running I get a request with parameters (i don't know the exact amount in advance), a function name and a class name. I load the class at runtime and want to call the method that is given in the request. My question is now:
How can I call the function with a changing amount of parameter?

```
myClass.getMethod(this.metaData.getFunctionName(), java.lang.Integer);
```

This would be a normal call.
But I want something like this

```
myClass.getMethod(this.metaData.getFunctionName(), ..args);
```

or like this

```
myClass.getMethod(this.metaData.getFunctionName(), for(param p: in request = new param));
```

I know that this isn't possible but is it possible in another way? Or do I have to know the exact amount in advance?

EDIT solution:
@LppEdd posted the solution and @DawoodibnKareem said it in the comments too. If you have a function that is defined with (...args) you can pass an array and every single element of the array counts as a passed argument.

I know that this is very insecure but the security is in some way given in that project.

rgds,
Dennis

Comment: Sounds dangerous. Who's sending this request?

Comment: Are all the parameters of the same type?

Comment: Are you looking for https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/variable-arguments-varargs-in-java/ ?

Comment: A client is sending this request and the parameter are of different types they can even be custom objects.

Comment: This sounds terrifyingly insecure.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem this is how the function is defined but I have to call a function like that. I hope you know what I mean ^^

Comment: @LouisWasserman I know

Comment: Then don't do it.

Comment: @nCap, no I have no idea what you mean.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem Lets say we have an array arr[int a, int b] and a function add(int ...args). How can i "paste" every single variable of the array into the function call like add(arr[0], arr[1]) if the size of the array is only known at runtime and can differ. It could be int a , int b, int c or even more and every single array element have to be in the function call. Can I do that dynamically?

Comment: @nCap see answer.

Comment: You can just write `add(arr);`.  A method that takes a varargs will also accept an array.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem But does the array count as a single parameter or as many as the array holds? If I would do this Integer.class.getMethod(name, parameterTypes) and would parse the array instead parameterTypes does that count as an array or does every single element of the array count as a single parameter?

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem ok I got it now. Thank you^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want something like

```
private Class<?>[] buildParameterTypes(final List<String> types) {
    return types.stream()
                .map(typeStr -> {
                    try {
                        return Class.forName(typeStr);
                    } catch (final ClassNotFoundException e) {
                        throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
                    }
                }).toArray(Class[]::new);
}
```

Usage

```
myClass.getMethod(this.metaData.getFunctionName(), buildParameterTypes(strTypeList));
```

The request must send the parameter types as a `String` array.

```
[
  "java.lang.String",
  "java.lang.Integer",
  ...
]
```

But, yeah, don't do this.
Btw, are you talking about a web request? Which kind of request?

Comment: That is the solution. But my upvote won't be visible. It comes from a post request and this request gets mapped to a Request object. But the security is given in some sort in this project ^^.